# Como pego dados do Axios e retorno em um componente de função no React?

Tags: javascript, react, component

Tô tentando pegar o id da URL, pra mostrar um post específico da API. Não posso usar componente de classe, porque useParams só funciona com funções. Eu tentei botar os dados dentro da variável post, mas não funcionou.

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

const Post = () => {
    let params = useParams();
    let post = null;
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + params.post_id)
    .then(res => {
        post = res.data ? (
            <div>
                <h4>{res.data.title}</h4>
                <p>{res.data.body}</p>
            </div>
        ) : (
            <div>Loading post...</div>
        );
    });
    
    return (
        <div>{post}</div>
    )
}

export default Post
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não está funcionando pois vocẽ não está utilizando um estado, e sim uma variável normal. Dessa forma o react não "sabe" que ele tem que reagir a mudança deste estado.

Utilize o `useState` para definir qual o estado inicial e a função de alterar este estado;

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

const Post = () => {
    let params = useParams();
    const [post, setPost] = useState(null);
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + params.post_id)
    .then(res => {
        setPost(res.data ?
        (
            <div>
                <h4>{res.data.title}</h4>
                <p>{res.data.body}</p>
            </div>
        )
        : 
        (<div>Loading post...</div>));
    });

    return (
        <div>{post}</div>
    )
}

export default Post
```